# What is the appropriate exception to throw for an Object being passed in and needing to be cast to the generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, exception, casting

```
public IPredefinedInterface
{
    void DoSomething(Object obj);
}

public class MyClass<T> : IPredefinedInterface
{
    public void DoSomething(Object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is T)) throw new ???

        SomeOtherFunc((T)obj);
    }
}
```

Not sure what the appropriate exception here is... ArgumentException, InvalidCastException, etc?

Comment: this looks like a design problem: your `MyClass<T>` is applying restrictions to the `DoSomething()` routine that really shouldn't be there. Imo violation of Liskov substitution principle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Are generic constraints not an option? e.g. enforce the contract on the method signature at compile time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: @Neil: No, generic constraints are not an option. The interface is not something I wrote or belongs to me, so I can't control that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a problem with the argument, so `ArgumentException`. You haven't actually *done* the cast, so `InvalidCastException` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the example of `IList`, which supports `Add` operations using type `object`. When implemented by the generic `List<T>`, you get an `ArgumentException` for invalid types.

```
var list = new List<int>();
var ilist = list as IList;
ilist.Add("A");
```

Result:

> ArgumentException: The value "A" is not of type "System.Int32" and
>   cannot be used in this generic collection.Parameter name: value

In examples like this, I might tend to follow the precedents set by BCL classes unless there are compelling arguments against it.

Comment: User m-y added some observations from reflecting the library into the answer that I'm not sure adds to the discussion, but if you're interested in the implementation details, check the revision history. (No offense taken to the edit, but I think it's not altogether necessary to see.)

Comment: No offense taken. Just pointing out that you are right, MS handles non-generic to generics exactly this way. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making a generic interface:

```
 public interface IPredefinedInterface<T>
 {
       void DoSomething(T obj)
 }
```

Then implement like so:

```
 public clas MyClass<T> : IPredefinedInterface<T>
 {
      public void DoSomething(T obj)
      {
           // It's now always T, eliminating the need for an exception
      }
 }
```

If you can't go with that pattern (because you want to be able to pass any type in), then I would suggest going with a context specific exception for that class:

```
 public class InvalidMyClassInputException : ApplicationException
 {
      public InvalidMyClassInputException(object obj)
         : base("An invalid call to DoSomething was made with object of type: " + obj.GetType().Name)
      {
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a cast causes an exception (or if something cannot be cast), a InvalidCastException is appropriate.

However, re-architecting your code may be a better solution, and allow compile-time checking:

```
public IPredefinedInterface<T>
{
    void DoSomething(T obj);
}

public class MyClass<T> : IPredefinedInterface<T>
{
    public void DoSomething(T obj)
    {

        SomeOtherFunc((T)obj);
    }
}
```

Then you don't even need to check because the environment and/ or compiler is doing it for you, which lets your code be much more simple.